# Mysql display random 4 users with more than 5 articles

Tags: php, mysql

I have users table and also articles tables. Article table contains articles submitted by users. I am working on a sql query to display random 4 users with more than 5 articles. user_id is stored in articles table. I have searched around in stackoverflow and google even though there are some similar questions, i couldn't find anything specific to mine.

Can anyone let me know if this question has been answered before and give me a link if yes otherwise I have the following query:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users WHERE type = 3 
  INNER JOIN articles ON 
    users.user_id = articles.user_id HAVING COUNT(user_id) > 5
```

This doesn't seem to work. I will appreciate any help to improve this query.

Database table is as follows:

```
USERS:
  user_id
  username
  email
  type

ARTICLES:
 id
 user_id
 title
```

For example, total user count is 100. User with user_id 49 has 10 articles, and another user with user_id 50 has 20 articles and the rest of the users have less than 5 articles. So the query should return only the user 49 and 50.

Hope this makes sense.

regards

Comment: can you provide with the tables an image would work even

Comment: Your example says `SELECT * 
  FROM users WHERE type = 3 ...` but then the schema you're showing doesn't have a column named `type` for table `users`. Could you please post an accurate description of your schema and also provide sample data as requested by @scaisEdge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've mocked up some table data to test my query.  `WHERE` clauses must be positioned after `JOIN`s.  You are also a little ambiguous about the comparison of `COUNT` AND `5` -- if you want more than 5 then `>5`, if you want 5 or more then `>=5`.

SQL:  ([SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/370676/2))

```
SELECT a.user_id,a.username,COUNT(b.user_id)
FROM users a
INNER JOIN articles b ON a.user_id=b.user_id
WHERE a.type=3
GROUP BY a.user_id 
HAVING COUNT(b.user_id)>5
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You have where join and having in wrong position, you missed  group by for a correct functioning of having 
and you need  an order by rand and limit 4

```
SELECT u.user_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN articles a ON  u.user_id = a.user_id 
WHERE a.type = 3 
group by u.user_id 
HAVING COUNT(a.user_id)>= 5
order by rand() limit 4
```

Comment: I think it should be "order by rand()". It returns no result.

Comment: show a proper data sample and the expected .. result  .. if don't return a result depend  by the data  ... too

Comment: show a proper data sample in tabular format  ..and a resume for the expected  result  .. we need  a valid data set for refine the query  +